# How to use PubSub Rest API with Google service accounts?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there anyway by which we can call the Google PubSub Rest API using the Google service account ?

I have a very specific requirement to publish messages on pub sub using the rest api, let me know is there any way with which it can be done ?

If there is a way to get the required Api Key or token for rest api using the service account that helps as well.

Comment: It won't work with API key. But yes, it's possible to get an access token with service account. What's your language?

Comment: guillaume blaquiere it's  Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the API directly, without the client library, you can do like this

Firstly, get the `access_token` and then add it in the header of your request

```
    const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
    const auth = new GoogleAuth()
    const adc = await auth.getApplicationDefault()
    const access_token = await adc.credential.getAccessToken();
    console.log(access_token.token)

    const request = require('request');

    const topic = 'projects/gbl-imt-homerider-basguillaueb/topics/go-hello'

    const options = {
        url: ' https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/' + topic + ':publish',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token.token,
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body:'{"messages":[{"data":"' + Buffer.from("Hello World").toString('base64') + '"}]}'
    };

    request(options, function(err, res, body) {
        let json = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(json);
    });
```

**EDIT**

I'm sadly too bad in Nodejs to achieve a clean code for this. You can go to the [documentation page](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/google-auth-library/5.1.0/classes/GoogleAuth.html) and you can see there is [constructor options for `GoogleAuth` class](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/google-auth-library/5.1.0/interfaces/GoogleAuthOptions.html)

At the end something like this should work (but I didn't achieve this... too bad...)

```
const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: '',
    keyFile: 'path/to/key.json'
})
```

Because I'm bad, I'm doing this and it works

```
//Set manually the environment variables
process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='path/to/key.json'
const auth = new GoogleAuth() //Use default credentials
```

Comment: Thanks could you please point me to an example where i can achieve this by passing client email private key  in runtime rather then using it from application defaults.

Comment: Also how can a service account with pub sub publisher role achieve the same.

Comment: I edited with dirty code because I'm not a node developer! Hope this help, and you will do something better than my workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example restApi call from AWS Lambda function to GCP pub/sub.
I tried to find a way to pass the service_account.json file to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable on my lambda function but unfortunately couldn't find it so I decided to go rest API version instead of the SDK version. So I extract the client email and the private key from service_account.json(I added it on the AWS secrets manager and fetch it from there)

```
  const { JWT } = require("google-auth-library");
  const topicName = "test-topic";

  const client = new JWT({
    email: process.env.GCP_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    key: process.env.GCP_PRIVATE_KEY,
    scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
  });

  module.exports.publisher = async (event) => {
    console.log(event.body);
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(event.body).toString('base64');
    const url = `https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/${topicName}:publish`;
    const options = {
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        messages: [
          {
            data: dataBuffer
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    const res = await client.request(options);
    console.log(res.data);
    return res.data;
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to use pub sub, You need to create IAM service account and enable pubsub service in google cloud console.
Use the following function to publish and subscribe.

Publish :

```
const pubsub = new PubSub()  
const data = 'this is data : ' + new Date().toString();
     const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
     const topicName = 'ypur-topic-name';

     pubsub
       .topic(topicName)
       .publisher()
       .publish(dataBuffer)
       .then((messageId) => {
         console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
         return res.status(200).json({ success: true });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
         console.error('ERROR:', err);
       });
```

Subscribe :

```
const pubsub = new PubSub();

    const subscriptionName = 'your-subscription-name';
    const timeout = 6000;

    const subscription = pubsub.subscription(subscriptionName);
    let messageCount = 0;

    const messageHandler = (message) => {
      console.log(`Received message ${message.id}:`);
      console.log(`Data: ${message.data}`);
      console.log(`tAttributes: ${JSON.stringify(message.attributes)}`);
      messageCount += 1;

      // Ack the messae
      message.ack();
    };

    // Listen for new messages until timeout is hit
    subscription.on(`message`, messageHandler);
    setTimeout(() => {
      subscription.removeListener('message', messageHandler);
      console.log(`${messageCount} message(s) received.`);
    }, timeout * 1000);
```

You can refer to this tutorial for complete flow : https://blog.cloudboost.io/google-pubsub-tutorial-74dd5b948700